# Implementing Autocomplete in Discord.js v14 to Overcome 25 Choices Limit in Command Options

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I have a command named "create" where I want users to select a server type from a list of files located in the "server_creation" directory. Initially, I used the `choices` field to display these options. However, due to Discord's limit of 25 choices, I'm facing difficulties as the number of files exceeds this limit.

I've decided to switch to using the Autocomplete feature for a more user-friendly experience. My goal is to dynamically load and display files from the "server_creation" directory as options for the "type" parameter.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
import { ButtonInteraction, CacheType, EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandOptionType } from "discord.js";
import { APIApplicationCommandOptionChoice } from 'discord-api-types/v10';
import { DefaultCommand } from "../../../utils/types";
import fs from "node:fs";
import config from "../../../../config";
const cooldowns: Record<string, number> = {};
const COOLDOWN_DURATION = 60000; // 1 minute cooldown (in milliseconds)
type ServerType = keyof typeof config.available;

export default <DefaultCommand>{
  name: "create",
  description: "Create a server",
  stringOption: [
    {
      name: "type",
      description: "Server type",
      required: true,
      // Current implementation using 'choices'
      choices: fs
        .readdirSync(
          `${__filename.endsWith(".js") ? "./dist" : "."}/src/server_creation`
        )
        .map((x) => ({
          name: x.slice(0, x.length - 3),
          value: x.slice(0, x.length - 3),
        })).slice(0, 25),
    },
    {
      name: "name",
      description: "Server name",
      minLength: 5
    },
  ],
  run: async (client, interaction, remiiuwu) => {
    await interaction.deferReply({ fetchReply: true });
    // [Rest of your code]
  },
};
```

**Question:**

1. How can effectively implement the Autocomplete feature for the "type" parameter in Discord.js v14?
2. Is there a recommended approach for dynamically loading file options from a directory and displaying them as Autocomplete choices?

In an attempt to overcome Discord's limit of 25 choices in command options, I decided to switch from using the choices field to implementing the Autocomplete feature in Discord.js v14. Specifically, for the "type" parameter in my "create" command, I aimed to dynamically load and display files from the "server_creation" directory as Autocomplete choices.